# Sort ObservableList Objects by Their Value Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, javafx

I have a class Student with these fields:

```
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String imageLink;
private String email;
private String status;
private String fullName;
private int classId;  
private int percentage;
Button changeAttendanceButton;
ImageView attendanceImage;
ImageView photo;
```

Field "status" can have 2 values: 1. present, 2. absent

Then I have Observable List:

```
private ObservableList<Student> allStudentsWithStatus = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

So I store Students in this list. Each student has either present or absent status.

I need to SORT this ObservableList by status. I want students with present status be first in that list.

Any tips?

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Use the `List.sort(Comparator)` method along with the appropriate `Comparator`. By appropriate I mean a `Comparator` that returns a value based on `status`. Also, since you're using an `ObservableList`, take a look at [SortedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html).

Comment: Specifically, you can just do `allStudentsWithStatus.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getStatus))` to sort the list in place, or `SortedList<Student> sortedStudents = new SortedList<>(allStudentsWithStatus, Comparator.comparing(Student::getStatus));`. In either, replace `Comparator.comparing(Student::getStatus)` with `Comparator.comparing(Student::getStatus).reversed()` to reverse the order.

Comment: Off-topic, but I'm not really sure why you would use a `String` for something that has two possible values, BTW. Why not use a `boolean`?

Comment: Thank you @James_D it works! I want to add: "Not submitted yet" status maybe later.

Comment: Then an `enum` would still be more appropriate than a `String`, no?

Comment: I am working with the database, so I am taking String from there. I have never used enum before, so I need to learn it first. But thank you, I will be thinking about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.You can create custom **Comparator**:

```
class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {
      return student1.getStatus()
               .compareTo(student2.getStatus());
  }
  //Override other methods...
}
```

or create like this

```
Comparator<Student> studentComparator = Comparator.comparing(Student::getStatus);
```

and then use one:

```
ObservableList<Student> allStudentsWithStatus = ...
```

```
Collections.sort(allStudentsWithStatus, studentComparator);
```

or use like this

```
allStudentsWithStatus.sort(studentComparator);
```

2.Use [**SortedList**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html) (`javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList<E>`):

```
SortedList<Student> sortedStudents = new SortedList<>(allStudentsWithStatus, studentComparator);
```

3.Use **Stream API** and **Comparator**, if you need to other actions or need to collect to other **Collection** *(the slowest way)*:

```
allStudentsWithStatus.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> i.getStatus()))
        //other actions
        //.filter(student -> student.getLastName().equals("Иванов"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        //.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```